# Why is my div not scrollable, and how to make it so?

Tags: html, css, reactjs, jsx

I am trying to display some data on a website I am working on.  I created a div with all the information in it, but since the information seems to overflow from the div, i cant see all of it.  I can see a scroll bar at the edge of the divider, but i cant seem to use it, since it is grayed out.  Here is a screenshot of my issue https://i.stack.imgur.com/iw8eY.png.   I need to be able to get to the bottom as there are three buttons there that i cant access without the scroll, but I cant figure out what I am supposed to do.  I'm fairly new to web development, so i might be missing something really obvious,

```html
<div className="learn-content mdl-typography--text-center"  style={{width: '80%', margin: 'auto'}}>
                <div className="grid">
                  <div className="card mdl-shadow--2dp">
                    <div className="card__title mdl-color--indigo mdl-color-text--white">
                      <h4 className="card__title-text">Purchaser Information</h4>
                    </div>
                    <div className="card__supporting-text mdl-color-text--white-600" id="messagesDiv">
              
                      <p>Legal Name: {legalEntity}</p>
                      <p>Operating Name: {operatingName}</p>
                      <p>Role: {string_role[role]}</p>
                      <p>Address 1: {address1}</p>
                      <p>Address 2: {address2}</p>
                      <p>City: {city}</p>
    //many more lines of information here <-- not actually in code.
                <div>
                <Button accent ripple onClick={this.approve.bind(this,key_name,role)} className="mdl-color-text--indigo btn btn-primary">Approve</Button>
                <Button accent ripple onClick={this.reject.bind(this,key_name,role)} className="mdl-color-text--indigo btn btn-primary">Reject</Button>
                <Button accent ripple onClick={this.return_back.bind(this)} className="mdl-color-text--indigo btn btn-primary">Back</Button>
                </div>
```

there is more information to display, i just did not watnt to show the entire document of code as there are over 1000 lines.   Please let me know

Comment: Can you please show your css?

Comment: i mean, the only formatting i have is this: style={{width: '80%', margin: 'auto'}}

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to add something like this to your CSS:

```
#messagesDiv {
overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

Comment: i tried adding this, and its not valid syntax in jsx. i get errors when i run it.  unexpected token and the like

Comment: What is jsx? (genuine question)

Comment: in JSX...  <div className="card__supporting-text mdl-color-text--white-600" id="messagesDiv" style={{ overflowY: 'auto' }}>

Comment: @JeffMcCloud, thanks for the reply.  I got the scrollbar to show, but for some reason it is grayed out even though there is more content to show.  do you know why this is?

Comment: Did you use overflowY: 'scroll' ??  if so, it should be 'auto' instead of 'scroll'

Comment: @JeffMcCloud thanks.  changed that.  I also had to add a position:'relative' parameter to get it to work.   thanks again